# Firebase data pushed but retrieval immediately after results in Null Pointer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have an app, and for this I run a method `checkData()` in the `onCreate` to make sure the required child nodes exist, and if not, create them (Since I want to make sure everything works even for the first user).
I call `updateUI()` in the `onStart`. This retrieves the data from the respective node and updates a few textfields respectively. 
I suddenly started getting an error here after adding some code that does not use either of these methods (Error persists even after removal of said code so its not the problem).

If I remove the `updateUI()` call, the node is created properly and everything works in subsequent runs of the program, but an immediate call to `updateUI()` after `checkData()` tells me that my data doesn't exist and the node is not created as well. I cannot find what's going wrong here and I'm at a loss.

```
public void checkData()
    {
        //Checks if the "users" table exists in the database, and populates it with the current user if it doesn't
       // mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this);
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild("users"))
                {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    User user = new User(mUser.getUid(), mUser.getDisplayName(), mUser.getEmail(), "", "Chennai", cal);
                    mDatabase.child("users").child(mUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
                    mUsers = mDatabase.child("users");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });

        //Checks if the current user exists in the "users" table, and adds it if it doesn't
        mUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                //Log.e("Data Change", snapshot.getValue().toString());
                if (!snapshot.hasChild(mUser.getUid()))
                {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    User user = new User(mUser.getUid(), mUser.getDisplayName(), mUser.getEmail(), "", "Chennai", cal);
                    mUsers.child(mUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
    }


public void updateUI()
{
    Log.e("Update UI", "Called");

   eText_passName = findViewById(R.id.eText_passName);
   eText_passName.setText(mUser.getDisplayName());
   eText_date = findViewById(R.id.eText_Date);
   eText_time = findViewById(R.id.eText_Time);

   //Gets DateTime String and sets it in the fields
   mCurrentUser = mUsers.child(mUser.getUid());
   mCurrentUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
   {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
       {
           User u = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);


           String dt = u.getDt();
           String dtArr[] = dt.split(" ");

           eText_date.setText(dtArr[0]);
           eText_time.setText(dtArr[1]);

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
       {

       }
   });

}
```

**The Error:**

```
12-29 00:54:30.720 26411-26411/com.namsnath.cabplanner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.namsnath.cabplanner, PID: 26411
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.namsnath.cabplanner.User.getDt()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.namsnath.cabplanner.MainActivity$3.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:152)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

The error is the call to u.getDt() in updateUI()
It seems the data writing gets interrupted somewhere but I cannot find out where. The logs show nothing out of the blue either.

EDIT:
Could this be due to a slow internet connection that doesn't allow the DB to update before the data is called?
If this is so, isn't Firebase supposed to store a local copy? Is this not accessed?

EDIT 2:

```
    public class User
{
    String uid, username, email, group, destination;
    //CustomCal c;
    String dt;

    User()
    {}

    User(String uid, String username, String email, String group, String destination, Calendar cal)
    {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.group = group;
        this.destination = destination;

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy KK:mm");
        dt = null;
        try
        {
            dt = format.format(cal.getTime());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        /*int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);*/
    }
}
```

The data I write is in this form:

```
cabplanner
  users
    userUID
      Data from user class
```

Comment: Please post your User class and the data that you write. There's probably a mismatch between what your User class has declared and what you write

Comment: Also do post a snapshot of your db

Comment: As a reference to people seeing this post later, once the given node is present, dataSnapshot can directly be used. For the first time when data is being added, a loop through dataSnapshot seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datasnapshot.getValue can possibly return multiple results. Try this:

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   User u = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
   ...
}
```

Comment: He has attached a listener to the narrowed down child node, i don't think that's the issue. There's mostly a mismatch causing the type casting to User.class to fail

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. Even if only one result exists, it contains a _list of one result_.

Comment: The snapshot may contain multiple children yes, but he's mapping it to a class which should map to all the children. The entire node will map to one user, if done correctly... He hasnt done the mapping correctly as far as i can guess

Comment: Your answer while technically correct is irrelevant to this case. You're used to using each child individually.

Comment: This actually worked. I'll try out a few more things and accept it as the answer if it works everywhere. Thank you so much @Yuliwee.

Comment: Also, the first time I ran it, I forgot to change it to "snapshot" inside and ran it as dataSnapshot.getValue() and it worked. I take it out of the loop and it doesn't work. Can someone explain this? It makes no sense

Comment: One more thing, my given code was working for the past 3 days, suddenly stopped last night. And now works using the same code but in a loop.